# how to add calendly widget to wordpress menu

Tags: javascript, wordpress, calendly

I am new to wordpress and would like to add calendly to the menu

I have the clendly widget that is the "pop up text" option

this is my widget code

```
<!-- Calendly link widget begin -->
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<a href="" onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/yapsody-customer-success/talk-to-an-expert'});return false;">Schedule time with us</a>
<!-- Calendly link widget end -->
```

I have a wordpress site setup, in the wordpress menu I would like a menu item called "demo" and would like the following behavior

1. user clicks on demo in the menu
2. the calendly widget opens

I am having an issue to add this functionality to the menu item click